# Convert csv to HTML table

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv, html

I have a `Medical.csv` file with rows of following format,

```
    field: 'participation.type', displayName: 'program_type', type: 'String',path:'participation'
    field: 'participation.program', displayName: 'program_name', type: 'String',path:'participation'
```

I want to write a **bash script** to convert it to HTML table with `field`, `displayName` and `type` as headers dynamically.

The `Csv2HtmlConverter.sh` (Inspired by answer at [Convert csv to html table using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256320/432903)) is

```
    echo "<table>" ;
    while read INPUT ; do
            echo "<tr><td>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</td></tr>" ;
    done < Medical.csv ;
    echo "</table>"
```

The result for above script is as below which is fine to some extent but I want to add `<th>field</th>`, `<th>displayName</th>` dynamically.

```
<table>
<tr><td>field: 'participation.type'</td><td> displayName: 'program_type'</td><td> type: 'String'</td><td>path:'participation'</td></tr>
<tr><td>field: 'participation.program'</td><td> displayName: 'program_name'</td><td> type: 'String'</td><td>path:'participation'</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
echo "<table>" ;
print_header=true
while read INPUT ; do
  if $print_header;then
    echo "<tr><th>$INPUT" | sed -e 's/:[^,]*\(,\|$\)/<\/th><th>/g'
    print_header=false
    continue
  fi
  echo "<tr><td>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</td></tr>" ;
done < Medical.csv ;
echo "</table>"
```

Explanation of the regex used is `sed`:

```
:[^,]*(,|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will  match `: 'participation.type',` and `:'participation'\n` (`$` means end of input/line in regex).

Comment: Works perfectly to my requirements. Respect.

Comment: Images courtesy of https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Didn't understand, why separate sed processing is needed for header?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [sqlite](https://sqlite.org) and the command-line program `sqlite3`, you can run that program and then:

```sql
.import --csv input.csv tmp
.mode html
.output output.html
select * from tmp;
```

You may need to add something to the resulting HTML file, e.g.

```html
<!doctype html>
<table>
```

so that it is recognized by browsers.

As a bash script, this could be

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TMP=`mktemp csv.XXXXX`
trap "rm -f $TMP" EXIT
(echo .import "$1" tmp; echo .mode html; echo .output "$TMP"; echo 'select * from tmp;' ) | sqlite3
awk 'BEGIN{print "<!doctype html><table>"};{print}' < "$TMP" > "$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell script that will convert a CSV to HTML:

http://giantdorks.org/alain/bash-and-awk-to-convert-delimited-data-csv-tsv-etc-to-html-tables/

To address your use case specifically.

Assuming the following original CSV:

```
$ cat original.csv 
field: 'participation.type', displayName: 'program_type', type: 'String',path:'participation'
field: 'participation.program', displayName: 'program_name', type: 'String',path:'participation'
```

You may want to modify it slightly:

```
$ echo field,displayName > modified.csv
$ awk -F"'" 'OFS="," {print$2,$4}' original.csv >> modified.csv
```

To produce the following cleaned up version:

```
$ cat modified.csv 
field,displayName
participation.type,program_type
participation.program,program_name
```

Then running the script linked earlier on the original CSV, will produce the following HTML:

```
$ csv2htm.sh --head original.csv 
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>field: 'participation.type'</th>
        <th> displayName: 'program_type'</th>
        <th> type: 'String'</th>
        <th>path:'participation'</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>field: 'participation.program'</td>
        <td> displayName: 'program_name'</td>
        <td> type: 'String'</td>
        <td>path:'participation'</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Running it on the cleaned up CSV, would produce:

```
$ csv2htm.sh --head modified.csv
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>field</th>
        <th>displayName</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>participation.type</td>
        <td>program_type</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>participation.program</td>
        <td>program_name</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: The script, at first glance, doesn't seem to handle quoted cell contents (that even might span multiple lines).

Comment: Right, it does not. Could certainly add quoted cell handling or just preprocess with something like: `sed 's/"//g' input`

Comment: Or, if data also contains double quotes: `sed 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/","/,/g;' input.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
host=`hostname`
now=`date +"%d-%b-%y"`
now=`echo $now| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
yest=`TZ=CST+24 date +%d-%b-%y`
yest=`echo $yest| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
sub="Jobs-$host-$now-HealthReport"

if [ -s jobs.csv ]
then
awk 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print "<HTML>""<TABLE border=1 width='100%' align='centre' ><tr bgcolor='#000080'><TH><FONT COLOR='#FFFFFF'>HSCR-DBMSJOB HEALTH REPORT  </TH></FONT>"
print "</TABLE>"
print "<HTML>""<TABLE border=1 width='100%' align='centre' bgcolor='#C6C6C6' BORDERCOLOR='#CCFF00' ><tr bgcolor='#5F9EA0'><TH>SUMMARY</TH>"
print "</TABLE>"
print "<HTML><TABLE border=2 width='100%' align='centre' BORDERCOLOR='#330000' ><trbgcolor='#FFFFCC'>"

print "<TH>BROKEN</TH><TH>SCHEMA_USER</TH><TH>JOB_ID</TH><TH>LAST_DATE</TH><TH>LAST_SEC</TH><TH>THIS_DATE</TH>"
print "<TH>THIS_SEC</TH><TH>NEXT_DATE</TH><TH>NEXT_SEC</TH><TH>NAME</TH>"
}


{
    printf "<TR>"
            for(i=1;i<=10;i++){

                      if(i == 1 && $i == "N" || i == 4 && $i == n || i == 4 && $i == y )
                    {
                            printf "<TD bgcolor='#75923C'>%s</TD>", $i
                    }
                    else if(i == 1 && $i == "Y" || i == 4 && $i != n && $i != y)
                    {
                            printf "<TD bgcolor='#FF0000'>%s</TD>", $i
                    }
                    else
{
                            printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
}
            }
            print "</TR>"
    }

END{

            print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
    }' y="$yest" n="$now" jobs.csv > jobstatus-$host-$now.html
else
echo "file not found"

fi
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your code for better readability. And add some comments...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer to this question, but will help those googling for a solution, for converting bash command output to html table format. There is an easy script available to do this at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/ which can be used to convert any command output or file to a nice html table format.